# PHP : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: php

In .htaccess I put it as shown below. But I keep getting an error.

> **Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https:...' from origin 'https://...' has been blocked by CORS**
> **policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the**
> **requested resource.**

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "PUT, POST, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "Accept, Authorization, Content-Type"

RewriteEngine On
Options All -Indexes

# ROUTER WWW Redirect.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ROUTER HTTPS Redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ROUTER URL Rewrite
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Suggestion: Use path-only URLs in async requests if your front and back ends are on the same host. Eg, instead of `"https://www.example.com/entrar"`, just use `"/entrar"`

Comment: I tried several things and nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one Allow origin header so the last one is interpreted.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, POST, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Accept, Authorization, Content-Type"
```

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://...' (redirected from 'https://...') from origin 'https://...' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://...' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
scripts.js:2          

GET https://.../entrar net::ERR_FAILED 200

Comment: Now blocked again but for another reason

Comment: You are trying to access a website that is not yours and you depends on their policy… because here every CORS is allowed with my code.